# Regular expression to remove leading space

Tags: regex

What is the meaning of ^([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)?

How can I change this to avoid leading space, but can have multiple space in between texts.

Example.
This should work

This should not work as it has a space before this

Comment: Is the question mark intended: `^([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)`? versus `^([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)?
```

Will match one or more Latin letters, decimal digits, or whitespace characters at the beginning of the string, all of which might be optional.

To avoid matching any leading whitespace, simply change it to:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)?
```

The final pattern will match one Latin letter or decimal digit, or whitespace characters at the beginning of the string, followed by one or more Latin letters, decimal digits, or whitespace characters, all of which might be optional.

Note that the `?` at the end is pretty confusing. If this is the entire pattern, it's probably not necessary at all, but I have a feeling this is just part of a larger pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)?
```

Selects **optional** 1 or more of following at the start:

`English letters (both upper case OR lower case) OR digits OR spaces`

**PS:** This can even match an empty string because of `?` in the end.

To avoid matching leading space use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$
```

**You should really provide some examples of what text you are trying to match.**

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you want?

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+
```

[example](http://www.rubular.com/r/TvzVFbFwJh)